# Pluralization issue in the tag's top users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, top-users, plurals

In the tag's top users page, for the user those who are answered or asked a single post only, for those entries the tooltip is displaying with the plural issue.

for answers:   1 answer**s** provided
for questions: 1 question**s** asked

For example, check the [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badges/topusers) top users page.

[image: Top users page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now:

For answers:

[image: "1 answer provided"]

And for questions:

[image: "1 question asked"]